# How to add padding/change space between lines in Alacritty terminal?

Tags: terminal

I installed Alacritty and its cool and all but because of my ZSH shell (I'm on Manjaro Gnome). It has a lot of emojis and it cuts some of those visuals:

[image]

Here is the native gnome terminal:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the font settings? See [.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Cogitri/e8d5c63818443f3c8f13cd7760fe77aa)

Comment: No. I have no idea how to do that. I have never done it for a terminal. How should I do that?

Comment: You edit the file and then restart your terminal

Comment: @DavidPostill Perhaps you could tell _which_ file?

Comment: I told you above `.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml ` in your home directory

Answer (score 5):

#### Update March 2024

Alacritty now uses [TOML](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0) as configuration file format. So the appropriate configuration would be:

```
[font]
offset.x = 0  # For letter spacing (default: 0)
offset.y = 0  # For line spacing (default: 0)
```

You can get a complete documentation about the configuration [here](https://alacritty.org/config-alacritty.html).

#### Old answer

Put these settings in `font` section in your `~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml`:

```yml
# NOTE: Values can be changed.
font:
  offset:
      x: 0    # For letter spacing (default: 0).
      y: 0    # For line spacing (default: 0).
```

[See more](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/alacritty.yml#L175-L180) at alacritty's documentation.